# После вставки текста в textarea не обновляется запись в Базе данных

Tags: php, html, mysql

Вообщем, когда вставляю текст в `textarea` просто скопировав его перед этим и после этого сохраняю запись, то она не обновляется. А если вручную писать текст, то работает...

**Я даже не знаю в чем проблема..в `textarea` или в самой базе данных.**

```
<?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "main", "main");
        $db = mysql_select_db("awesome");
        mysql_set_charset("utf-8");

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $result = mysql_query(" SELECT title, text, author, time FROM users WHERE id='$id' ");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

            $title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
            $text = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
            $author = strip_tags(trim($_POST['author']));

            $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET title='$title', text='$text', author='$author' WHERE id='$id'");
            mysql_close();
        }
    ?>

    <div id="page" class="container">
        <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
            <br>
            <p>Назва</p>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" required>
            <br><br>
            <p>Текст</p>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" cols="80" rows="15" maxlength="500" required><?php echo $row['text']; ?></textarea>
            <br>
            <p>Автор</p>
            <input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $row['author']; ?>" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="send" value="Зберегти зміни">
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger">Скасувати</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Учебник прошлого века по изучению php выкиньте на помойку ;)

Comment: @Visman, посоветуйте что-то..Я слышал о `PDO`..но не знаю что к чему

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/pdo http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Visman, хорошо, спасибо.. сейчас посмотрю. Это хоть не прошлый век?)

Comment: Нет, не прошлый.

Comment: @Cactus попробуйте взять имена столбцов и таблиц, в SQL-коде, в апострафы (`)

Comment: @wcobalt, странно, но не работает..

Comment: @Cactus сарказм? Еще добавьте ; в конец SQL-запросов. И добавьте вывод mysql_error().

Comment: Попробуйте мониторить ввод (вар-дампом). При нажатии копи-паст возможно появление доп. символов (сам наступал)

Comment: @DNS, ну просто в скобочках пишет кол-во знаков или что, не понял..Но серавно не ясно, ПОЧЕМУ НЕЛЬЗЯ ВСТАВИТЬ АААА

Comment: @wcobalt, не сарказм..но ошибок нету..

Comment: @Cactus точки с запятыми добавили?

Comment: Ну так - подготовьте запрос к БД и перед выполнением дайте вывод для контроля на экран. Думаю, ошибка проявится

Comment: @wcobalt, да,да..

Comment: @wcobalt, вот кинул на хост `inbusiness.zzz.com.ua`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select_form.phtml

```
<div id="page" class="container">
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $row['author'];?></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Изменить">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить">
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

edit_form.phtml

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
    </html>
    </div>
   <div id="page" class="container">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <br>
        <p>Назва</p>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" required>
        <br><br>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="text" cols="80" rows="15" 
        maxlength="500" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <p>Автор</p>
        <input type="text" name="author" value="" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="send" value="Зберегти 
        зміни">
        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger">Скасувати</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

index.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("awesome");
mysql_set_charset("utf-8");

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT id,title, text, author, time FROM users");
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
$id=$_POST['hidden'];
include "edit_form.phtml";
exit();
}
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$id=$_POST['id'];
$title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
$text = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
$author = strip_tags(trim($_POST['author']));
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET title='$title', text='$text', 
author='$author' WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_close();
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
include "select_form.phtml";
```

esport bazy

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Май 23 2017 г., 01:07
-- Версия сервера: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- Версия PHP: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- База данных: `awesome`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `text`, `author`, `time`, `title`) VALUES
(2, 'Hello World', 'Halib', '06:13:31', 'Hello World'),
(3, 'My friend', 'Loky', '07:22:40', 'My friend');

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```